# UIGraphicsBeginImageContext cutting off image

Tags: uiview

this is my code I'm using to convert a UIView to UIImage and then emailing it out. When I go to send the new image its cutting off the sides but not the bottom.  I do have a scroll view in place because the image is larger than the screen.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewSubs.bounds.size);
[viewSubs.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this on a retina screen device so that the scale factor is 2.0? Try to use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(viewSubs.bounds.size, YES, 0.0f);` instead to automatically set the scale factor to that of the main screen.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! it is the retina screen. Unfortunately it didnt work but thanks for 'ContextWithOptions' for the retina display. Is there a way to change the size of the layer?

Comment: Could you share some kind of sample of how the interface looks and how the resulting wrongly rendered image look?

Comment: hey Matt! what I did was just change from 'Aspect Fill' to 'Aspect Fit' and it made the Image a tad bit smaller but it works. I can send it to you if you like , can u message your email ?

Comment: You can't post them here? make a simpler example if you don't want to expose customer information etc.